# How to call a method multiple times in Android

Tags: java, android, performance, function, methods

I would like to ask, If is there a better way to call a method in android multiple time.
But What I really want to know, is how to delay which **`showToas("Message 1");`** call for 10 second and only after call the next.

Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...


    showToas("Message 1");
    showToas("Message 2");
    showToas("Message 3");
    showToas("Message 4");
    showToas("Message 5");
    showToas("Message 6");
    showToas("Message 7");
        ...


    private void showToas(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

**UPDATED**

This is the away I managed to get it to work.
giving each method call a 5 sec break, But I think there most a be better way to implement this function ? Can you advice please. Thanks

```
private void CallMultipleToast(){

         Runnable call_1 = new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 Toast("Message one");


                     Runnable call_2 = new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             Toast("Message two");


                                 Runnable call_3 = new Runnable() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void run() {
                                         Toast("Message three");
                                         //CAN I ADD MORE
                                     }
                                 };//end call_3
                                 new Handler().postDelayed(call_3, 5000);


                         }
                     };//end call_2
                     new Handler().postDelayed(call_2, 5000);

             }
         };//end call_1
         new Handler().postDelayed(call_1, 5000);


}
```

Comment: try to use `Handler.postDealy()` and `Runnable`.

Answer (score 2):

try this way

```
 Runnable r2=new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     showToas("Message 1");
                }
            };

new Handler().postDelayed(r2,1000);
```

do the same for others and increase Time Delay

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code, base on your exmaple, could you please advice. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Timer` for that:

```
//global variable counter
int counter = 1;

Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showToas("Message "+counter);
        counter++;
    }

}, 0, 10000);  //It will be repeated every 10 seconds
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code, base on your exmaple, could you please advice. thanks

Comment: Its totally different code, you used. Did you try timer?

Comment: Sorry   MysticMagic, I meant to ask you. Base on my new updated code. would I be able to use Timer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for(String str : array){
                    showToast(str);
                    Thread.sleep(10000L);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ToastShow {
private Context context;
private Toast toast = null;
public ToastShow(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
}
public void toastShow(String text) {
    if(toast == null)
    {
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else {
        toast.setText(text);
    }
    toast.show();
}
```

}

and you can call  toastShow(String text) many times it only changes the content of toast